Will ip_route_input return EHOSTUNREACH?
Recently I have been learning about Linux bridge, and I found that the br_nf_pre_routing_finish function will call the ip_route_input function and determine whether the return value of ip_route_input is equal to EHOSTUNREACH. But I further found that ip_route_input does not seem to return EHOSTUNREACH. Can anyone point out whether this is a bug or whether I have missed some points? The linux version is v6.8. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8/source/net/bridge/br_netfilter_hooks.c#L388

ip_route_input does return EHOSTUNREACH in some cases. Actually, if you go through its function calls, you'll see that ip_route_input_slow sometimes returns EHOSTUNREACH (see lines 2308 and 2330 for example). This is the following code path:
br_nf_pre_routing_finish
 ip_route_input
  ip_route_input_noref
   ip_route_input_rcu
    ip_route_input_slow


I have noticed these two statements. But there is a goto statement (goto no_route) behind both of them, and then will pass through two other goto statements: goto no_route -> goto local_input -> goto out, and err is assigned a value of 0 at line 2402. In this case, are the assignments at lines 2308 and 2330 still valid?

I'm not sure if I have a misunderstanding of the goto statement, or I have missed some points.

Hmm, indeed. But it looks like err (i.e., when == EHOSTUNREACH) is cached in the skb's rtable, see line 2384 and then line 2401). Not sure how it helps regarding the return value from ip_route_input though.
